# How to refer to main domain without hard-coding its name?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a domain name: TestSite.com. I create several subdomains for this site and refer to them as first.TestSite.com, second.TestSite.com, etc.

How do I refer to TestSite.com **relatively** without having to hard code its name in an html or aspx file in first.TestSite.com? What I mean is (using folders as example) if I have a folder TestSite and a sub folder first

> TestSite/first

, then from first I can refer to its parent TestSite folder by

> ../

What do I use to refer to TestSite.com from first.TestSite.com? Thanks.

Comment: Folders are a nested hierarchy.  Subdomains are not.  Subdomains can introduce problems for javascript and cookies and ssl certificates.  It can even introduce problems for things like image caching - is blank.gif from first.testsite.com the same image as blank.gif from testsite.com?  It is not, to a browser.

Comment: Subdomains can also cause issues for search engine spiders and rankings, if that matters to your case.

Comment: @BrianWhite is right SSL. Additionally, SSL will only work with one IP address (with Apache). So even if you had the money to buy SSL certs for each subdomain they would need to have their own IPs. Which might not be possible depending on your ISP  limitations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no way using pure relative links.  You have to program it as a string manipulation.

Something like:

```
var host = location.host;
var lastPeriod = host.lastIndexOf(".");
var remainder = host.substring(0, lastPeriod);
var afterSecondLastPeriod = remainder.lastIndexOf('.') + 1
var baseDomain = host.substring(afterSecondLastPeriod);
console.log(baseDomain);
```

EDIT: Shorter version using regex:

```
var baseDomain = host.match(/[^.]*\.[^.]*$/)[0]
```

This is general, so it will always return the last part.  Regardless of whether it's `a.TestSite.com`, `b.a.TestSite.com`, etc. it will return `TestSite.com`.

You will have to modify it if this assumption is not correct.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep your relative links, you can use the [`base`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4) element.

> [The base element's href] attribute specifies an absolute URI that acts as the base
>   URI for resolving relative URIs.

So, add a `base` element, specify the `href` you'd like, and all the relative URIs on the page now use the URI you've specified as the *base* URI.

```
<head>
    <base href="http://testsite.com" />
</head>
```

That's all you need. However, if you'd like to make things a little cleaner, you can pull that URI from the web.config using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`. Here's an aspx snippet:

```
<head>
    <base href="<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rootdomain"] %>" />
</head>
```

And the web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add name="rootdomain" value="http://testsite.com" /> 
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

This method allows you to affect many elements from *one* and its value can be driven from the web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question ASP.NET, I'm going to assume you want to do this server-side, so you are not relying on JavaScript on the client-side to generate HTML links.

First of all, make sure you have a web.config file in your subdomain sites, and add this to the configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add name="MainDomain" value="example.com" /> 
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Using this setting in your ASPX pages, hyperlinks on one of your subdomains' pages would look like this:

```
<a href="<%$ AppSettings: MainDomain %>">Go to main domain home page</a>
<a href="<%$ AppSettings: MainDomain %>/products.aspx">Go to products page on the main domain</a>
```

The setting with `name="MainDomain"` will be read from the configuration file, and inserted into the page where it says `<%$ AppSettings: MainDomain %>`. This way, you are creating the required HTML on the server-side, with no hard-coding required.

If you need to change the name, simply update the configuration file, and all pages will automatically use the new domain name.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution would be to use the original domain name for the live server, but point it to your development environment.

You can override DNS lookups in Windows by adding lines to this file.

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Add the following using a text editor.

```
127.0.0.1   www.livesite.com
127.0.0.1   first.livesite.com
127.0.0.1   second.livesite.com
```

These domains will now map to the locahost. So there won't be a need to hack HTML for testing.

Comment: Warning, pointing multiple domains to 127.0.0.1 always causes me problems in weird ways.  It has never turned out to be the simple solution to the complicated problem that I was facing.  I have tried it in many different situations and always end up reverting it.

Comment: @Brian: There's nothing wrong AFAIK with pointing multiple hostnames to 127.0.0.1, any more than there is with pointing multiple hostnames to any other IP address. It does, however, mean that you need to configure your development webserver to do name-based virtual hosting (unless you _want_ all your development sites to look identical).

Comment: @BrianWhite the majority of web developers use hosts to point multiple domains to their localhost. Otherwise it's not possible to work on more then one website. As only one site can be configured to operate off of localhost. What I do is change the .com to .local for all my sites. Example; www.thinkingmedia.ca becomes www.thinkingmedia.local on my dev machine. I currently have 50+ local sites running without any issues. Sorry you had trouble, but if you start a new question about the issues. I'd be glad to help.

Comment: Will you catch any of the cross-site, caching, or ssl cert issues you'll have in prod in dev in the above set up?  @Matthew, I'm not talking about actually different sites, but different parts of the same site that just get different names