# subdomain url redirects to the main url

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, subdomain

I developed a website in asp.net and hosted on windows server which does not provide me the wild card entry for the subdomain name. How can I write my url as e.g
http://subdomainName.DomainName.org?

I want to redirect the url with a subdomain to the main domain; so url  "subdomainName.DomainName.org" should redirect to "DomainName.org", where my subdomain name is not fixed. The subdomain will be assigned to each user.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What? Do you want to redirect *.domain.org -> domain.org? I guess URL rewrite module can help you achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

The `subdomain` is part of the DNS server, and work together with the IIS setup.

So, you can NOT change the DNS setup from asp.net, neither the IIS setup. When a provider gives your the access to add extra sub-domains, what is actually do is that create new entries on the DNS entry, and then add map that to the IIS, so that sub-domains to look at your site. If your provider did not have give you a tool to add sub-domains, nether you can edit the DNS entries, then you can NOT add them from asp.net.

If you can add sub-domains then you can manipulate what you going to server and show on global.asax at `Application_BeginRequest` using the `redirect` or the Rewrite the path. For example:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    var SubDomain = GetSubDomain(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host);

    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SubDomain) && SubDomain != "www")
    {
       Response.Redirect("www.yourdomain.com", true);
       return;
    }
}

// from : http://madskristensen.net/post/Retrieve-the-subdomain-from-a-URL-in-C.aspx
private static string GetSubDomain(Uri url)
{
  string host = url.Host;
  if (host.Split('.').Length > 1)
  {
    int index = host.IndexOf(".");
    return host.Substring(0, index);
  }

  return null;
}
```

Similar posts:
[How to remap all the request to a specific domain to subdirectory in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491454/how-to-remap-all-the-request-to-a-specific-domain-to-subdirectory-in-asp-net/11492451#11492451)
[Redirect Web Page Requests to a Default Sub Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393441/redirect-web-page-requests-to-a-default-sub-folder/11393756#11393756)
[How to refer to main domain without hard-coding its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961996/how-to-refer-to-main-domain-without-hard-coding-its-name)
[Retrieve the subdomain from a URL in C#](http://madskristensen.net/post/Retrieve-the-subdomain-from-a-URL-in-C.aspx)

Comment: Correction: HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host